# How can I access to parameters.yml content within a custom twig extension

Tags: php, symfony

How can I access to parameters.yml content within a custom twig extension?

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Twig;

class HashExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function hash($param)
    {
        return sha1($param . $this->container->getParameter('secret'));
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('hash', array($this, 'hash')));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hash_extension';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject container or a single parameter to your extension when you register it - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service

```
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        arguments:
            - @service_container
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**UPDATE:**

Have you heard/used dependency injection in Symfony before?

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class HashExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function hash($param)
    {
        return sha1($param . $this->container->getParameter('secret'));
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('hash', array($this, 'hash')));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hash_extension';
    }
}
```

Comment: I added `@service_container` argument part but I still cannot access `$this->container->getParameter('secret')`. Getting "ContextErrorException: Undefine Property: $container"

Comment: Probably not important but using the container mean this is dependent on the Symfony Container. A better way would be to pass the necessary parameters into the extension via the `__construct()`. Although if you don't care about the dependency then it's not important.

Comment: @dmnptr - Your solution is better so I'll use it instead.

Comment: @Qoop - Is there an example for this note of yours so that I can check it out - "_A better way would be to pass the necessary parameters into the extension via the __construct()_"

Comment: Rather than using `@service_container` you would use the actual parameter on it's own `%parameter%` or as an array `[%parameter1%, %parameter2%]` and then in your extension you would have `__construct($secret)` or `__construct(array $parameters)`. Like I said though, if you are not worried about decoupling it from Symfony then it's not as much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted with:

**I'm passing global Symfony code to twig from the controller:**

```
return $this->render(.... `'staticCode' => $this->container->getParameter('secret'));`
```

**Creating the URL with this:**

```
<a href="{{ path('delete_process', {'hashId':brand.id|hash(staticCode) }) }}">Delete</a>
```

**Extension:**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Twig;

class HashExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function hashFilter($param, $staticCode)
    {
        return sha1($param . $staticCode);
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('hash', array($this, 'hashFilter')));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hash_extension';
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    car.twig.hash_extension:
        class:  Car\BrandBundle\Twig\HashExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```